# X-ray mode doesn't look the same as video

Tags: mesh, interface

I decided to try my hand at blender. I got the donut tutorial done and just have do the beginner modeling and the intermediate tutorials from Mr. Blender Guru. I ran into a bit of an issue with the x-ray mode where it doesn't look the same as the video. (I use Blender 2.90.1)

[image: Mr. Blender Guru's x-ray mode] Here is his x-ray mode.

[image: Here is mine] Here is mine.

I am very confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Subdivison Surface modifier, uncheck "Optimal Display".

Comment: Aw yiss! Thanks! I upvoted your commented but for some reason it won't show. (probably because I just joined). Thanks for responding.

Comment: @GroundedHog you should be able to click the tick mark to accep the answer ✔️